# Jenkins Windows Service Not Starting

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins **was** up and running for months without issue, as a windows service.

I did some Jenkins updates (copied a newer/later .war file to the .jenkins folder) and some windows updates also occurred. The version that I have is **Jenkins 2.263.3**.

I did a lot of trolling through the documentation and other StackOverflow tickets and found out that the JENKINS_HOME environmental variable was missing. I added this.

Here is what my investigation reveals.

1. The Java environment variable is set - see below:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

2. JENKINS_HOME environmental variable is set - see below:

```
C:\>echo %JENKINS_HOME%
C:\Users\XXXXX\.jenkins
```

3. The Installation was under user XXXXX and the service account Log On was configured accordingly
   [image: Service Log On Properties for Jenkins]
4. I do not have another application using port 8080 - I checked this with sys internals.
5. My jenkins.xml looks like this:

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  <!--
    if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
    The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
  -->
  <executable>java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
  <!--
    interactive flag causes the empty black Java window to be displayed.
    I'm still debugging this.
  <interactive />
  -->
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>

  <onfailure action="restart" />
  
  <!-- 
    In the case WinSW gets terminated and leaks the process, we want to abort
    these runaway JAR processes on startup to prevent corruption of JENKINS_HOME.
    So this extension is enabled by default.
  -->
  <extensions>
    <!-- This is a sample configuration for the RunawayProcessKiller extension. -->
    <extension enabled="true" 
               className="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension"
               id="killOnStartup">
      <pidfile>%BASE%\jenkins.pid</pidfile>
      <stopTimeout>10000</stopTimeout>
      <stopParentFirst>false</stopParentFirst>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  
  <!-- See the referenced examples for more options -->
  
</service>
```

6. **I can start Jenkins from the command line as follows:**

```
java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Users\XXXXX\.jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="C:\Users\XXXXX\.jenkins\war
```

7. If I try start it from the Serice Manager I get this error - System.BadImageFormatException
   [image: System.BadImageFormatException]
8. One last thing,  once I start Jenkins from the command line, and login to the the application, I note the following Jenkins System log:

```
Feb 17, 2021 10:29:31 AM INFO hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
Jenkins is fully up and running
Feb 17, 2021 10:29:57 AM WARNING hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle getBaseDir
Could not find environment variable 'BASE' for Jenkins base directory. Falling back to JENKINS_HOME
```

Any suggestions how to get the service to start via the Service Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is starting and stopping without issue.

The problem I suspect was that the original install of Jenkins was very old, and I presume that it may have been a 32-bit application at the time. The current updates seem to 64-bit apps. Since the original install, Jenkins was updated - with changes spanning several major releases from the original install (.war file updates). **The jenkins.exe file - that starts the service was never updated.**

The error message 'System.BadImageFormatException' after much research indicated that the issue was related to compatibility difference between 32/64 bit executable. I presume it was expecting a 64-bit executable but was getting a 32-bit exe.

To solve this problem I installed the latest version of Jenkins on my local PC.

On the Server I backed up the files:

- jenkins.exe
- jenkins.exe.config

I then stopped Jenkins on the Server, where the Service was not Starting (from the terminal window with Ctrl+D).

I then replaced these 2 files on the server with the latest files from my local installation.

Service started the first time.